rsync archive to copy files from MacOs to TerraMaster DAS (ExFAT file system)
I'm trying to copy files from my MacBook with Sonoma 14.1.2 to TerraMaster D2-310 configured with ExFAT file system, GUID partition table.
I decided to use rsync (version 3.3.0) but if I use flag: -a or -t and then I check the copied files, they have the creation and modification dates as now, not the real ones.
It also happens when I use rsync to copy files to my Maxtor Hard Disk.
If I use rsync -a or rsync -t on the same files to a different directory on my Mac, they are copied in the correct way, with correct times.
I also tried using sudo with no success.
Has anyone had the same issues? Is this a known issue? How do I solve it? Thanks
UPDATE:

if I run rsync -t the creation and change timestamp are both now.

if I run rsync -t again, the creation timestamp is now, but the change timestamp is the correct one.


This is very weird, I would like not to copy everything twice to make it work as expected.
